Remove plotly tick labels
I wanted to make a plotly 3d graph with no tick labels but I failed to find a way to do so
I tried fig.update_layout(xaxis=dict(showticklabels=False)) but the tick labels still appears.
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(-1,1,100)
y = np.linspace(-1,1,100)
x_mesh, y_mesh = np.meshgrid(x,y)
z = x_mesh**2 + y_mesh**2

fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Surface(x=x,y=y,z=z,colorscale='Sunsetdark_r')])
fig.update_layout(xaxis=dict(showticklabels=False))

fig.show()

Output image
I needed to remove the marked numbers.

Slightly different syntax for 3d charts, try this:
fig.update_layout(
    scene=dict(
        xaxis=dict(showticklabels=False),
        yaxis=dict(showticklabels=False),
        zaxis=dict(showticklabels=False),
    )
)


https://plotly.com/python/reference/index/ and the sub-pages referenced on the left of that page are great for finding obscure parameters in Plotly.
